# return a pdf in browser from web service

Tags: web-services, pdf, servlets

i am relative new in java development..
I want to create a web service (jax-ws)/web application that will receive some input and generate pdf, and then open the pdf in the browser. I manage to create the pdf (using itext) and open it in the broswer using servlet (with FileInputStream etc).
However i do not know, how to return the servlet from the web service.
What should I do, so when I call the web service to receive a pdf via the servlet ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've returned PDF from servlet, it means your servlet sent PDF stream as output and probably set content type as "application/pdf". This works fine in the browser and this is the right way to do it.

However, you cannot easily invoke web service (no matter whether it is JAX-WS or any other stack) from the browser. Web service call requires POST and strictly defined SOAP content. You can, however, use AJAX to call web service, but that is a different story (also look at REST).

If you want to return binary data from web service (please keep in mind that web-services are for machines, not for humans using web browsers), you have two options: either serialize the binary data using base64 or use multipart HTTP response (MTOM standard, see for instance: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-attachment-with-mtom).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So in order to pass the pdf to the client and use web services, i have to "upload" the generated pdf, via a web service's method, using stream/byte arrray. Then convert this byte array to a string encoded to base64 (?), and return string as the return type of the web method ?
After that, the web service client (such as servlet), will retrieve the data, using the same logic that was used to upload the pdf the first place ?